# How to resolve' h.Animated.Text.propTypes.style is undefined' when it doesnt exist anywhere in react-native project?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

I just upgraded to RN v0.63.3 and the endless upgrade nightmare continues.

so far I have: manually upgraded from 0.61.5 -> 0.63.3 run npm install run pod install added arm64 to Excluded Architectures for debug and release variants

Now xcode will build (after the arm64 exclusion), but running fails with a JS exception:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RCTFatalException:
> Unhandled JS Exception: TypeError: undefined is not an object
> (evaluating 'h.Animated.Text.propTypes.style')', reason: 'Unhandled JS
> Exception: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
> 'h.Animated.Text.propTypes.style'), stack: @1179:2569 v@2:1473
> @1175:312 v@2:1473 @1174:186 v@2:1473 @1171:296 v@2:1473 @1170:185
> v@2:1473 @1131:354 v@2:1473 @658:3564 v@2:1473 @626:215 v@2:1473
> @422:206 v@2:1473 @421:195 v@2:1473 @418:228 v@2:1473 @6:57 v@2:1473
> d@2:875 global code@1353:3 ' terminating with uncaught exception of
> type NSException CoreSimulator 732.17 - Device: iPhone 11
> (43CE6CFD-B48A-45AA-B0D4-9BC99E70C55B) - Runtime: iOS 14.0 (18A372) -
> DeviceType: iPhone 11 (lldb)

Any idea what this means and how to fix?

NOTE: I no longer have react-native-material-textfield in my node_modules. so even though initially editing that module cleared this error, i ended up removing the module, because the patch described in #1208 of @react-native-community/cli didnt work for me.

running stills fails with same error. a search of `h.Animated.Text.propTypes.style` only exists in the main.jsbundle. not sure how why thats out of sync, but i deleted the main.jsbundle file as well. the error persists. Ive cleaned react-native chache, cleaned build folder.

Xcode: v12.0.1   |  iOS: 14.0.1  |  React-native: v0.63.3

Comment: I'd highly recommend that you **1st** Create a brand-new RN project with the target version. **2nd** install dependencies **one by one** and make sure you have a successful build after each one... finally, copy your source-code folder...

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli it sounds like you dont have an application in production, because creating a whole new project and copying src is just not feasible. you have EVERY single package (~30) which needs to be integrated (not a simple npm I/link), in my case firebase needs native integration also, my CI/CD pipeline, not feasible at all.